# ActorNotFound Exception trying to run Spark 1.3.1 on windows 7

Tags: apache-spark, akka

We are at a road block trying to understand why Spark 1.3.1 doesn't work for a colleague of mine on his Windows 7 laptop. 
I have pretty much the same setup and everything works fine for me.

I searched for the error message but still didn't find a resolution.

Here is the exception message (after running spark 1.3.1 vanilla installation prebuilt for Hadoop 2.4)

```
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
        at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:164)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:596)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://sparkDriver/deadLetters), Path(/)
]
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$DefaultPromise$$dispatchOrAddCallb
ack(Promise.scala:280)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.onComplete(Promise.scala:270)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection.resolveOne(ActorSelection.scala:63)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection.resolveOne(ActorSelection.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.makeDriverRef(AkkaUtils.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.startDriverHeartbeater(Executor.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalActor.<init>(LocalBackend.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend$$anonfun$start$1.apply(LocalBackend.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalBackend$$anonfun$start$1.apply(LocalBackend.scala:107)
        at akka.actor.TypedCreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(Props.scala:343)
        at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
        ... 9 more
```

**Related Issues:**

Searching for this issue online didn't yield a lot of results, which seems to point that this is a very rare and specific problem:

- I have seen this error mentioned, but for Linux, not windows: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Actor-not-found-td22265.html
- This one also doesn't seem to offer any resolution: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/UqCYeUpgGCU

My assumption is that this is related to some resolving / IP conflicts etc, but I'm not sure.

**More details**

- JDK 1.7 64 bit, Windows 7 64 bit, Spark 1.3.1 prebuilt for Hadoop 2.4
- We ruled out all firewall related issues, we looked at all blocked traffic and it was not there
- We tried "run as an administrator" with no luck.
- We tried both Spark submit and spark shell, the most straightforward Spark "Hellow World" didn't work.
- We did get the UI at localhost:4040, the job is marked as started, but is waiting forever (e.g. even `sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).count()` never finishes
- No other errors were found in logs
- One difference that I did notice between my system and my friend's: when I do ping localhost, I get 127.0.0.1, when he does it he gets ::1 not sure if it's related, but I saw an issue about spark having problems with ipv6, and saw it was resolved only in 1.4, is that related? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6440

I'm sure it's a network / security / permissions related issue, but we can't seem to be able to pinpoint it

Any ideas where to look next?

Comment: btw, what scala version did you use? I am using 2.11.. i wonder if it caused this problem.. :/

Comment: @David - 2.10, but good news, we upgraded to Spark 1.4 and the issue was resolved!

Comment: upgrading to Spark 1.4 and downgrading to scala 2.10, now everything works fine.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Spark 1.4.0 seems to have resolved that issue.

It could be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6440 but can't tell for sure.